# JDK installation: sudo does not run the bash file properly

Tags: bash, java, sudo, jdk, netbeans

I was trying to install NetBeans along with JDK from [*Oracle*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html) website. However, I had an issue that the installation produced an exception in thread *main*(I have run `chmod +x` already), I was executing the bash file through this command:

```
sudo sh /home/user/jdk-installation-nb-file.sh
```

Then, when I executed it without `sudo`, It executed successfully without not errors. My question is what did the `sudo` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html#linux) say:

> You do not have to be a root user to use this installer unless you choose to install this bundle in a system-wide location.
>   (…)
>   **Note**: If you choose to install this bundle into a system-wide location such as /usr/local, you must first login as root to gain the necessary permissions.

It's not saying “You **must** not be a root user”, however they may have built in a test to assure the script doesn't save files with root permissions and ownership – which would mean a normal user would not be able to use the installation later *despite* being installed under `/home`. That's nothing more than a wild guess, but would actually make sense.